# Difference between updating a product vs recreating a product in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am a newbie in Magento.. I have created a script to create a product with images, Stocks and Categories on the fly, and is working fine.. I have to update the products frequently.. Is there any difference between updating a product vs removing and creating the product again.

```
if (in_array($id, $skuids)) {
   $newproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $id);

    $newproduct->delete();

 $newproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

 }
//create script goes here
```

This is what i am doing now. In this case the magento ID changes regularly. will this affect anywhere in Sales ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Anything that keys off the product id will never match, you can have a thousand entries in history that have the identical sku but different product ids. So the first thing to do is a little research on how Magento handles history to see if it will be totally messed up.

Comment: I would not really bother about sales, but rather about wish lists, existing customer's cart, and a lot of other functionalities you will just mess up by removing products that should have been updated